# How to remove red border in phpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I have a little strange question, and I'm hoping you could help.
Cause, I've been searching for the answer in Google, in PHPstorm documentation and etc.

Here's what I need. Every time I type something in CSS or HTML with Zen coding, this Red Border appears to the value. When my mouse cursor is anywhere else and I hit "Enter", the cursor goes to the end of that red border.

So does anybody know, how to get rid of it? It drives me crazy.. 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You cannot remove/disable this **functionality** (see @lena answer). But if all what you want is just to get rid of the **border** (or change the border's color) then `Settings | Editor | Colors and Fonts | General | Live Template` -- remove or change `Effects` color.

Answer (score 7):

pressing Enter (or Tab) is enough to remove the border :) See [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html):
"If the selected template is parametrized and requires user input, the editor enters the template editing mode and displays the first input field highlighted with the red frame. Type your value in this frame and press EnterEnter or TabTab to complete input and pass to the next input field. After completing the last input field, the caret moves to the end of the construct, and the editor returns to the regular mode of operation"

Comment: It annoys me, too... Esc escapes this border the same way as Enter or Tab. But I don't udnerstand why I have to press additional key to leave it. I very often use arrow keys to go somewhere else or just click with a mouse.

Normally Enter/Tab/Esc goes to the end of the construct which also is not optimal for me (especially when the statement is quite long). That's why I use $END$ in the live template somewhere in the middle of the construct so that cursor doesn't go at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same unwanted behavior in PHPStrom with php.
For PHP the solution was to uncheck the following checkbox:

Go to Settings (ctrl + alt + s), then navigate to:

Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> PHP

Uncheck checkbox: "Enable smart function paremeters completion"